# How to unset NSFetchRequest's fetchLimit?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit) for Cocoa's `NSFetchRequest` `fetchLimit` property says:

> The fetch limit specifies the maximum number of objects that a request should return when executed.
>
> If you set a fetch limit, the framework makes a best effort to improve efficiency, but does not guarantee it.

However, it doesn't tell you how to unlimit the maximum number of objects that a request should return if the fetch limit has already been set.

How can I return an unlimited number of matching objects after the previously limiting the number of objects with `fetchLimit` on my `NSFetchRequest`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From some quick testing, the default value for `fetchLimit` when an `NSFetchRequest` is instantiated is 0, and setting the value to something other than 0 and then back to 0 will not limit the results returned.

So, as of Swift 4, set `fetchLimit` to 0 to return unlimited results.

Comment: Sadly missing in the documentation, but I suppose it makes little sense wanting to limit a fetch request to zero items.